# How can I add just a tiny bit of dynamism to a single HTML page, with minimal dependencies and maximum portability?

Tags: asp.net, html, jsp, dojo, cgi

I am making a web application that until now got away with only serving static HTML files (with all the main functionality being bundled in Javascript and some well-modularized webservices).

However, it turns out that Dojo, the Javascript framework I use, needs a small config parameter set by the server to make the internationalization [work correctly](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/internationalization/globalization-guidelines/locale-and-resource-bundle-guidelines.html#quickstart-internationalization-globalization-guidelines-locale-and-resource-bundle-guidelines). Basically all I will ever need to do is

- Inspect the Accept-Language HTTP header
- Echo some of that information in my generated HTML.
- (This will only be needed for a single page)

Now my problem is that I have zero experience in making a dynamic webpage and don't even know where to start and what tool to use. My first thought would be doing this in C#+ASP.NET (since I'm currently in a windows environment) or JSP (since then I'd be able to copy-paste the example from the docs) but I'm not confortable mindlessly adding a dependency to a framework when the rest of my pages are all static and thus very easily portable.

What technologies whould I consider, given my primary needs are **simplicity** and **portability**?.

Comment: You can definitely use C# and ASP.NET... I'd even suggest MVC, but that's just me. This is very easy to be able to do.

Comment: did my answer below make sense?

Comment: not that much :/ You answer is more of a generic asp.net page but I was hoping for either a comparison of different frameworks or a least a more specific example to help my particular use case (inpecting headers and so on)

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how to get the `Accept-Headers` bit. Unfortunately, the `Echo some of that information in my generated HTML` doesn't make much sense to me. Since you said your thought was to do it in C#, my first instinct was to give a C# example. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Chase Florell: Nice. I'm still having trouble making it run though. Do you know any good links for documentation that would help me? Most of the ones that I find seem to assume you are installing everything from scratch (i'm not) and are building a new website from scratch (I just want to replace a file in a current website)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure that I understand. If you're running IIS on a windows box, try copying the code I posted below into a `txt` document. Rename that document to `test.aspx` and load it up in the root of your website. Finally hit http://example.com/test.aspx and tell me what the result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done very easily. Here's an example of a stand alone page that can be wired up. It doesn't rely on any dependencies and runs on Windows.

---

**MyDynamicPage.aspx**

```
<%@ Language=C# %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title> MY TITLE </title>
   <meta> </meta>
   <script runat="server" language="C#">
   void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      // Get your dynamic settings here
      literalAcceptHeaders.Text = Request.Headers["Accept-Language"];
   }
   </script>
   <body>
      <form id="Form1" runat="server">
         <!-- page content -->
         <asp:Literal id="literalAcceptHeaders" runat="server" />
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```